# Latex package for American Typewriter font

Tags: xetex, pdftex

What is the latex package for [American Typewriter font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Typewriter)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have not known `slab serif` before.

Comment: if you have the font as truetype or opentype then you don't need any specific package just load the font using `fontspec` with lualatex or xelatex

Comment: If you own the font just install it in your normal place for fonts on your machine and use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile using the `fontspec` package to load it.